# Upper bound for the difference between two solutions of nonhomgenous Helmholtz pde

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$ be a smooth domain. Let $\mu_{i}: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ , $i=1,2$, $\mu_{i} \in C^{2}(\Omega) \cap C(\bar{\Omega}),f_{i} \in C(\bar{\Omega}) $ and 
$$
  \begin{cases}
               u_i - \Delta u_i=f_i, \: in \: \Omega\\
             u_i=0  \: in  \: \partial  \: \Omega 
            \end{cases}$$

I want to show that $||u_1-u_2||_{L^2} \leq ||f_1-f_2||_{L^2}$.  In my computation I need to prove that $||\Delta u_1- \Delta u_2||_{L^2}=0$ and I did not know how to show this. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v=u_1-u_2$. $v$ is a solution of $v-\Delta v=f_1-f_2$ with null boundary conditions. Multiply the equation by $v$ and integrate:
$$
\int_\Omega|v|^2+\int_\Omega|\nabla v|^2=\int_\Omega v(f_1-f_2)\le\|v\|_2\,\|f_1-f_2\|_2.
$$